# How can I click on a div button with selenium webdriver?

Tags: html, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-ide

I have this button:-

```html
 <div class="dsk-col-1-4 card new">
    <div class="div_center_div">
      <span class="icon icon_plus-black-symbol"></span>
      <h2>Create</h2>
    </div>
  </div>
```

But I tried with find element by classname:-

```
driver.findElementByClassName("dsk-col-1-4 card new").click();
```

But it does not work.
Any help?

Answer (score 2):

Move to your element and click. Example:

```
new Actions(driver).MoveToElement(yourElement).Click().Perform();
```

Answer (score 1):

The "by class name" locator usually expects a *single class name* to be passed:

```
driver.findElementByClassName("card").click();
```

If you want to use multiple classes, go with a "by CSS selector"

```
driver.findElementByCssSelector(".card.new").click();
```

Note that the `dsk-col-1-4` class is not a very good choice for an element locator - this looks very much like a layout-oriented class name which not only have a higher probability to b changed, but also does not bring any information about the element and it's purpose. `card` and `new` on the other hand are a better fit.

Comment: i get the css from that element :

driver.findElementByCssSelector("html body div.main div.addon_cards.fluidwrap div.dsk-col-1-4.card.new").click();

but it does not works.

Answer (score 1):

Ok so I couldn't understand exactly Which element you want to click on,
So based on my assumption , try below Xpaths :

1) if it is `<div class="dsk-col-1-4 card new">` that you want to click

```
//div[contains(@class,'dsk-col-1-4 card new')]
```

2) If it is  that you want to click,

```
//span[contains(@class,'icon icon_plus-black-symbol')]
```

3) If it is `<h2>Create</h2>` that you want to click,

```
//h2[text()='Create']
```

Hope this Helps!!

Answer (score 0):

Within your locator you're passing multiple class names, and although they are both assigned to the element the findElementByClassName function realy only works when it is a single class name. The way I'd do it would be to use findelement(By.Xpath()), in this instance you'd need to use

```
webDriver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[contains(@class,'dsk-col-1-4 card new')]")).click();
```